# dojo.connect VS <script type="dojo/connect"> (DojoML)

Tags: dojo, javascript-framework

First of all I want to say Im new in the DOJO world and probably for some persons this
question is stupid :). But also somebody says that there is no stupid questions.
Here is my problem:
I got a quick question related to DojoML (`<script type="dojo/connect">` to be more exact).
In an example here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree.html
we got somethin like this :

`<script type="dojo/connect">

var menu = dijit.byId("tree_menu");

menu.bindDomNode(this.domNode);

dojo.connect(menu, "_openMyself", this, function(e) {

    var tn = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
    menu.getChildren().forEach(function(i) {

        i.attr('disabled', !tn.item.children);

});`

});
`</script>`

Now I would like to translate it to "traditional" script.
As I read here : http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/08/09/dojoml-the-best-thing-since-sliced-bread/
such DojoML notation can be translated into :

`dojo.connect(oMyTree, 'postCreate', null, function(){});`

My question is if this is the right "translation" because it simply doesnt work.
My goal is to attach a simple right click menu to every MyTree's node.

Comment: that was easy :)   
we simply need to call once:    
`oMenu.bindDomNode(oTree.domNode);`    
That's it.

Comment: i have read some where i like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have read some where i like this. This kind of scripts will run once the widget enclosing them is instantiated. Basically  will append a extra handler to postCreate. But if you do  you are erasing the default postCreate and running your postcreate handler.